# Chrome Node is not registering to Selenium Hub after upgrading to Selenium Grid 4.0.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

We are using a docker-compose file for creating a selenium grid network and after upgrading to selenium grid version 4.0.0 we have found that the grid is not registering to the node.

In this case, we are always receiving the below error.

```
chrome_1    | 12:18:47.180 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: The hub responded with 404
```

We tried to revert back to the previous version and found that it is working fine. Can you help us identify why it is not working in Selenium Grid 4? Is there any additional settings required to be done? We tried to find in the Selenium Grid 4 official page, but couldn't find much.

Attaching docker-compose file for reference

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    selenium:
      image: selenium/hub
      ports:
        - 4444:4444
      environment:
        GRID_MAX_SESSION: 10
    chrome:
      image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
      shm_size: 2gb
      depends_on:
        - selenium
      environment:
        - HUB_HOST=selenium
        - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=10
        - NODE_MAX_SESSION=10
      ports:
        - 5901:5900
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the following about all the changes to the grid at the following link: [Docker images for the Selenium Grid Server](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/trunk#docker-images-for-the-selenium-grid-server)

Your docker-compose.yml file based on the above will now be:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    selenium:
      image: selenium/hub
      ports:
        - 4442:4442
        - 4443:4443        
        - 4444:4444
    chrome:
      image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
      shm_size: 2gb
      depends_on:
        - selenium
      environment:
        - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium
        - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
        - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
        - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
        - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=10
      ports:
        - 5901:5900
```

However, you need to read the full details from the link to ensure you have the correct setup

Comment: Grid is registering to the Node now. 
Thanks @djmonki.
However localhost:4444 is still not available for me. Since it is entirely a different issue, I will create a separate post for tracking it.

Comment: [http://localhost:4444/ui/index.html#/](http://localhost:4444/ui/index.html#/) is the grid console from your browser for grid v4

Answer (score 3):

Check out this example https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3.yml

I copied the values in that file and it worked for me.

From the [docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/trunk#docker-images-for-the-selenium-grid-server)